# <amp-ad> advertisements not displaying

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to serve my own AMP ads. I have code that was working a couple of weeks ago, but which has mysteriously stopped working. I've appended a trivial example here:

I can tell from the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab the the ad is  successfully invoking remote.html, which is successfully fetching the picture.

However, when I inspect the amp-ad tag itself, it is empty - there isn't even an empty iframe. It's as if it had loaded the iframe, fetched everything correctly, and the iframe has then destroyed itself.

HELP!!!

Here is the code of the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://dk-imac.local" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="amp-3p-iframe-src" content="https://localbtk.com/remote.html">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
    <amp-ad width=728 height=90 type="_ping_" data-fkslot='1'>
    </amp-ad>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of remote.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Remote PBL</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<script>
(function() {
var v = location.search.substr(1);
if (!(/^\d+(-canary)?$/.test(v))) return;
var u = 'https://3p.ampproject.net/'+encodeURIComponent(v)+'/f.js';
document.write('<script'+' src="'+encodeURI(u)+'"><'+'/script>');
})();
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
<div id="c" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;">
<script>
    // @todo Add in proper Google Analytics
    var trackJavascriptLink = function(url) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    };
    draw3p(function(config){    // Can add a second parameter "done" which is a function
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.write("<div style='width:" + (config.width - 16) + "px;height:" + (config.height - 16) + "px'>" + 
                        this.responseText + "</div>");
            }
        };
        x.open("GET", "https://localbtk.com/handler/amp-page/fetch-slot/" + config.fkslot + "/" + (config.width - 16) + "/" +
                (config.height - 16), true);
        x.send();
    },
      // List of expected amp-ad types.
      ['_ping_'],
      // List of hostnames that are allowed to embed this change.
      // Please also use ALLOW-FROM X-Frame-Options to get security in
      // browsers that do not support location.ancestorOrigins.
      ['dk-imac.local']); // My own has a few others also.
</script>
</div>
<script>if (window.docEndCallback) window.docEndCallback()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2016-Oct-10: I've posted this as an issue on the AMP project's Github page (see https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5442#issuecomment-252025995). There is an answer, as yet unsatisfactory, that this is expected behaviour and that `_ping_` is for testing only. However, they don't make any suggestions as to what I should do differently, which leaves me with creating code for a new "ad network" (which is really just my own site) as my only option. This is going to be a lot of work and feels like real overkill, but that's where I'm at for now.

Btw, here is an example: 
https://bachtrack.com/amptest.html

Comment: By the way, is there a list of older versions available on the CDN? At the moment, the file names on the CDN don't seem to change (https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js and https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js), but if I've understood it correctly, the developer documentation indicates that the code is being changed every Thursday.

Comment: Can you provide some example AMP URLs that contain your code? It will make it easier for people to debug the problem.